# How do you use Induction to connect to a local SQLite database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, induction

I'm trying to use [Induction](http://inductionapp.com/) to connect to my local SQLite database however I've no idea of how to make the connection. In previous SQLite clients I've simply opened the database file.

[image: Induction connection screen]

What properties should I be putting into these fields? My database is simply `development.db` and located inside my Rails application

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I open the sqlite3

Method 1: Fill in the first box `file://path/to/file/db.sqlite3`, select file adapter, fill in the  Database column with: `Path/to/yourdb.sqlite3`

Method 2: You can drag-and-dropping the sqlite3 file on the app icon.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and maybe one of you can help. I have the a database (data.db) in a folder named data on my desktop. So, the file path is /Users/username/Desktop/data/data.db. I've tried entering this into the fields, and I've tried drag-and-dropping the file. Neither has seemed to work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the path to the database in the Database field? Usually that's what SQLite requires.

Comment: It won't accept it unfortunately. I've tried putting it on the line that has `sqlite://` but that either hangs or crashes. A little confused :s

Comment: You could always try some of the other front-end applications like [Mesa](http://www.desertsandsoftware.com/?realmesa_home) or [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks tadman. I was using SQlite database browser but base looks nice. It was the visualization tools in Induction I was excited about - I'd like to grapple a bit with my data